# How to compute the sum $ 1+a(1+b)+a^2(1+b+b^2)+a^3(1+b+b^2+b^3)+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Could it be possible to find the solution for the following series?

$$ 1+a(1+b)+a^2(1+b+b^2)+a^3(1+b+b^2+b^3)+\cdots$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1! why poeple are voting to close this? it is simple and nice question, where did you get it from?

Comment: @Arjang I am trying to write a theoretical model in Economics. After solving several equations, I come up with this expression. I need to get the sum for solving my theoretical model.

Answer (score 9):

**HINT:**

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n\sum_{m=0}^n b^m=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n \frac{1-b^{n+1}}{1-b}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: No sir. I am very much new in this world - this type of series

Comment: @mjalam, do you know 'geometric series'?

Comment: This is pretty cool: when $b = 1$, this is the oft-asked series $\sum n r^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Yuriy Yes not very expert!

Answer (score 6):

Since the OP admitted that they can't continue from Dr.MV's hint, I'll do it myself:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n \frac{1-b^{n+1}}{1-b}=\frac{1}{1-b} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n-b \sum_{n=0}^\infty (ab)^n \right)=$$

Here we use geometric series, so we need to have $|a|<1$ and $|ab|<1$: *

$$=\frac{1}{1-b} \left(\frac{1}{1-a}-\frac{b}{1-ab} \right)=\frac{1}{(1-a)(1-ab)}$$

* Correction due to Batominovski's comment

Comment: Its wonderful! Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't actually need $|b|<1$, for $|ab|<1$ suffices.

Comment: @Batominovski, thank you, corrected

Comment: In principle, the two series on the right side of your first line might diverge and yet the series on the left side could still converge. Ultimately that  doesn't happen with this example, but it's not exactly obvious.

Comment: @alex.jordan, I just remembered this myself. Yes, that requires justification, in this case for the conditions on $a,b$ I mentioned both series converge absolutely, thus my actions are allowed. I think, it should be obvious, that if the addends diverged on their own, I wouldn't be able to evaluate the series that way

Comment: Also when $b=1$, as long as $|a|<1$, the series will converge. But any argument using the $\frac{}{1-b}$ factor assumes $b\neq 1$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $$S = 1+a(1+b)+a^2(1+b+b^2)+a^3(1+b+b^2+b^3)+\cdots$$  
Also we know, $$(1-b)(1+b+b^2+b^3 \cdots +b^n-1) = 1-b^n$$ 
We now start feeling that having $(1-b)$ as a factor in each term in the $RHS$ will create a "nice" series.
So multiplying the $LHS$ & $RHS$ by $(1-b)$, we get, 
       $$S(1-b) = (1-b)+a(1-b^2)+a^2(1-b^3)+a^3(1-b^4)+\cdots $$
Now, upon expanding the $RHS$, we get 2 geometric progressions,
     $$S(1-b) = (1+a+a^2+a^3+\cdots)-(b+ab^2+a^2b^3+a^3b^4+\cdots)$$ 
The first series is an infinite  GP ( here $|a|<1$ is a constraint) with the first term equal to $1$ and common ratio $a$. So its sum, $S_1$ (say) is given by, 
      $$S_1 = \frac{1}{1-a}$$ 
The second series is also an infinite GP ( here too $|ab|<1$ is a constraint). It's first term is $b$ and the common ratio is $ab$. It's sum, $S_2$ (say), is given by,
      $$S_2=\frac{b}{1-ab}$$
Combining $S_1$ and $S_2$ we finally get,
      $$S(1-b) = \frac{1}{1-a} - \frac{b}{1-ab}$$
Simplifying the $RHS$ and dividing both sides of the equation by $(1-b)$ we get,
                              $$S = \frac{1}{(1-a)(1-ab)}$$

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Anonymous_original Thanks everybody!

Comment: @miracle173 Yeah, thanks, I got it sorted out.

Comment: @Anonymous_original Can we use code from Latex in this website? How?

Comment: @mjalam This site uses MathJax. Check the answer to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22957/where-can-i-find-help-to-typeset-mathematics-from-the-editing-help-page). I think it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

A slight variant that requires no explicit cancelling of $1-b$ (so you needn't handle the $b=1$ case with a continuity argument) rearranges the double summation, viz. $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(a^n\sum_{k=0}^n b^k\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b^k\sum_{n=k}^\infty a^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b^ka^k\frac{1}{1-a}=\frac{1}{\left( 1-a\right)\left( 1-ab\right)}$$ provided $\left| a\right| < 1$ and $\left| ab\right| <1$.

Answer (score 2):

You have $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(a^n\sum_{m=0}^nb^m\right)\text{.}$$ Before determining what this converges to, it is worth establishing for which values of $(a,b)$ it converges at all. To that end, consider the Ratio Test:

$$\left\lvert\frac{a^{n+1}\sum_{m=0}^{n+1}b^m}{a^n\sum_{m=0}^nb^m}\right\rvert=\left\lvert a\left(1+\frac{b^{n+1}}{\sum_{m=0}^nb^m}\right)\right\rvert\to\begin{cases}\lvert ab\rvert&\lvert b\rvert>1\\\lvert a\rvert&\lvert b\rvert=1\\\lvert a\rvert&\lvert b\rvert<1\\\end{cases}$$

So it converges when:

- $\lvert ab\rvert<1$ and $\lvert b\rvert>1$
- $\lvert a\rvert<1$ and $\lvert b\rvert\leq1$

And diverges when:

- $\lvert ab\rvert>1$ and $\lvert b\rvert>1$
- $\lvert a\rvert>1$ and $\lvert b\rvert\leq1$

This test has been inconclusive when:

- $\lvert ab\rvert=1$ and $\lvert b\rvert>1$
- $\lvert a\rvert=1$ and $\lvert b\rvert\leq1$

Let's look at the last case first. If $\lvert a\rvert=1$, then you have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\pm_n\left(\sum_{m=0}^nb^m\right)}\text{.}$ The terms of such a series, $\pm_n\left(\sum_{m=0}^nb^m\right)$,  do not approach $0$ no matter what $b$ is. So your series will diverge.

What if $\lvert b\rvert>1$ and $\lvert a\rvert=\frac{1}{\lvert b\rvert}$? Since $\lvert b\rvert>1$ we may write $\sum_{m=0}^nb^m=\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}$, and your series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\pm_n\left(\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b^n(b-1)}\right)}\text{.}$ Again using $\lvert b\rvert>1$, the terms of this series do not converge to $0$, so this series would be divergent.

Now we know the only situations where your series converges are:

- $\lvert ab\rvert<1$ and $\lvert b\rvert>1$ (which implies $\lvert a\rvert<1$)
- $\lvert a\rvert<1$ and $\lvert b\rvert\leq1$ (which implies $\lvert ab\rvert<1$)

When $b\neq1$, both situations give:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(a^n\sum_{m=0}^nb^m\right)
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n\frac{1-b^{n+1}}{1-b}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-b}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n-b\sum_{n=0}^\infty (ab)^n\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{1-b}\left(\frac{1}{1-a}-\frac{b}{1-ab}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{(1-a)(1-ab)}\\
\end{align}$$

And when $b=1$ with $\lvert a\rvert<1$,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(a^n\sum_{m=0}^nb^m\right)
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a^n\\
&=\left.\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}x^{n+1}\right|_{x=a}\\
&=\left.\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1}\right|_{x=a}\\
&=\left.\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-1\right)\right|_{x=a}\\
&=\left.\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right|_{x=a}\\
&=\frac{1}{(1-a)^2}\\
\end{align}$$

Which conveniently agrees with the formula $\frac{1}{(1-a)(1-ab)}$.

Comment: Can we use code from Latex in this website? How?