# $S = \frac{1}{(1-a)(1-ab)(1-b)}$ or $S = \frac{1}{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)(1-ab)(1-ac)(1-bc)}$ etc.

Tags: sequences-and-series

From [How to compute the sum $ 1+a(1+b)+a^2(1+b+b^2)+a^3(1+b+b^2+b^3)+\cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892492/how-to-compute-the-sum-1a1ba21bb2a31bb2b3-cdots) was shown that :
$$ 1+a(1+b)+a^2(1+b+b^2)+a^3(1+b+b^2+b^3)+\cdots=\frac{1}{(1-a)(1-ab)}$$

Does permutations such as
$S = \frac{1}{(1-a)(1-ab)(1-b)}$ or $S = \frac{1}{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)(1-ab)(1-ac)(1-bc)}$ etc. lead to some sort of similar simple expansions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the first one and taking into account that $$\frac 1 {1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$ you would find that $$ \frac{1}{(1-a)(1-ab)(1-b)}=$$$$\left(1+b+b^2+b^3+b^4+b^5+b^6+b^7+b^8+b^9+b^{10}+\cdots\right)+$$ $$a
   \left(1+2 b+2 b^2+2 b^3+2 b^4+2 b^5+2 b^6+2 b^7+2 b^8+2 b^9+2
   b^{10}+\cdots\right)+$$ $$a^2 \left(1+2 b+3 b^2+3 b^3+3 b^4+3 b^5+3
   b^6+3 b^7+3 b^8+3 b^9+3 b^{10}+\cdots\right)+$$ $$a^3 \left(1+2 b+3
   b^2+4 b^3+4 b^4+4 b^5+4 b^6+4 b^7+4 b^8+4 b^9+4
   b^{10}+\cdots\right)+$$ $$a^4 \left(1+2 b+3 b^2+4 b^3+5 b^4+5 b^5+5
   b^6+5 b^7+5 b^8+5 b^9+5 b^{10}+\cdots\right)+$$ $$a^5 \left(1+2 b+3
   b^2+4 b^3+5 b^4+6 b^5+6 b^6+6 b^7+6 b^8+6 b^9+6
   b^{10}+\cdots\right)+$$  $$a^6 \left(1+2 b+3 b^2+4 b^3+5 b^4+6 b^5+7
   b^6+7 b^7+7 b^8+7 b^9+7 b^{10}+\cdots\right)+$$ $$a^7 \left(1+2 b+3
   b^2+4 b^3+5 b^4+6 b^5+7 b^6+8 b^7+8 b^8+8 b^9+8
   b^{10}+\cdots\right)+$$ $$a^8 \left(1+2 b+3 b^2+4 b^3+5 b^4+6 b^5+7
   b^6+8 b^7+9 b^8+9 b^9+9 b^{10}+\cdots\right)+$$ $$a^9 \left(1+2 b+3
   b^2+4 b^3+5 b^4+6 b^5+7 b^6+8 b^7+9 b^8+10 b^9+10
   b^{10}+\cdots\right)+$$ $$a^{10} \left(1+2 b+3 b^2+4 b^3+5 b^4+6
   b^5+7 b^6+8 b^7+9 b^8+10 b^9+11
   b^{10}+\cdots\right)+$$ $$\cdots$$ where appear some nice patterns.